# svg creates http instead https on non-absolute URL

Tags: url, svg, https

I'm using SVG on a page using HTTPS, but SVG creates an HTTP instead of HTTPS link to an image, causing that the browsers treat the page insecure. SVG is used with the following fragment:

```
<svg id="head-image-1000" width="1000" height="130" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g> 
        <a xlink:href="/">
            <image xlink:href="/layout/panorama-winter-1400.jpg" height="97" width="1000" y="0" x="0"/>
        </a>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Is the only possibility to use absolute URL?

Comment: the UA should use the same protocol as the parent document.

Comment: Wild guess: Does the same happen if you use the HTTP namespace URIs (`http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` and `http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink`)? I think it’s not correct to use HTTPS here.

Comment: unor is correct. It is incorrect to use https in the namespace values. Those values are defined namespace constants. They are not real URLs.

Comment: Thx. I've set back all `http://www.w3.org` to http.

Comment: My website has these links in the CSS files of plugins. When I complete a scan for links it says "insecure page". I was going to change them, but after seeing this post I didn't. I am wondering if this could affect SSL or your SEO for security, how does google view this link?   All links were HTTP to this site www.w3.org/1999/xlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by some caching in the browser (Firefox). After clearing the cache and restarting the browser the image is downloaded with HTTPS.